# Please explain sort() and compareTo()

Tags: java

I'm writing a code that compares twitter tweets.

Tweet constructor (Tweet class has implement Comparable) (declared inside Tweet.java):

```
   public Treet(String author, String description, Date creationDate) {  
   mAuthor = author;
   mDescription = description;
   mCreationDate = creationDate;

  }
```

Say I want to compare two tweets (declared inside Example.java):

```
   Tweet tweetOne = new Tweet("Hello reddit", "josh", new Date(18909042L);
   Tweet tweetTwo = new Tweet("Hello again reddit", "Susan", new Date (19419249L);
```

Then I made an array with these two tweets (declared inside Example.java)

```
  Tweet[] tweets = {tweetOne, tweetTwo]
```

Then sort (declared inside Example.java)

```
  Arrays.sort(tweets);
```

Here is my override compareTo() (declared inside Tweet.java)

```
  public int compareTo(Object obj) {

 Treet other = (Treet) obj;

 if (equals(other)) {

  return 0;
}

int dateCmp = mCreationDate.compareTo(other.mCreationDate);

if (dateCmp == 0) {

  return mDescription.compareTo(other.mDescription);

}

return dateCmp;
}
```

A few things really making me bang my head on my desk:

1) how does sortTo() call the compareTo() method, if it does at all?

2) if no1 is true then why is it compareTo(Object obj) instead of compareTo(Tweet twt); seeing as tweets is an array of Tweet class? Presumably:

```
 Array.sort(tweets) -----> compareTo(tweets) ?
```

3) if (equals(other)) what is equals to what here? Somebody told me that it is if(this.euqals(other)) but again what is this? Is it

```
   tweetOne.equals(other) or tweetTwo.equals(other) or Tweet.equals(other)?
```

4) mDescription.compareTo(other.mDescription), again what is the mDescription here if

```
  (other.mDescription) == ({tweetOne, tweetTwo}.mDescription)?
```

if I do this:

```
int val = mDescription.compareTo(other.mDescription)
```

What will val be?

I'm especially confused as to what is happening inside the compareTo() method as we want to compare tweetOne AGAINST tweetTwo but there are no evidence of that happening.

I hope someone can guide me through this, this is currently a huge road block for me atm.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Just pick any book on Core Java and it will explain these concepts quite well.

Comment: This will help a lot. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

compareTo method checks for below things.

- a negative integer if anObject < anotherObject
- zero if anObject equals anotherObject
- a positive integer if anObject > anotherObject

So in your case,

```
int dateCmp = mCreationDate.compareTo(other.mCreationDate);
    if (dateCmp == 0) {
        return mDescription.compareTo(other.mDescription);
}

 return dateCmp;
}
```

Here is how it goes,

- It first checks for dates, if dates are same, then compares the description.
- Tweet will be compared based on description.

This article will definitely help http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-1/

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate your answer a bit if you don't mind.

because the other contains {tweetOne, tweetTwo}

in the case of 

       mCreationDate.compareTo(other.mCreationDate)

what does mDescription in the first part contain? Is it the date of tweetOne or tweetTwo?

Comment: Please study the link provided, if it doesn't solve your problem I"ll be happy to help.

Comment: I've been looking at your link and it does have some really useful information.

However, I'm still struggling as to what this will return in that link you provided for example 

  return this.id.compareTo(employee.getId());

or in
            
mCreationDate.compareTo(other.mCreationDate)

Because say String fruitOne = "apple"; String fruitTwo = "orange";

then fruitOne.compareTo(fruitTwo) will return -1.

Comment: @kshatriiya Yes, because "a" < "o". `System.out.printf("%d %d %d%n", "a".compareTo("b"), "a".compareTo("a"), "b".compareTo("a"));`

Comment: @kshatriiya, your implementation will check for date first, if date is equal then it will check for description, based on which the order will be decided.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides two similar mechanisms for comparing two instances for the purpose of ordering; [`Comparable.compareTo(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) and [`Comparator.compare(T, T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). Both offer [three-way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison) (from the linked Wikipedia entry)

> Many object-oriented languages have a three-way comparison method, which performs a three-way comparison between the object and another given object. For example, in Java, any class that implements the `Comparable` interface has a `compareTo` method which returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer.

For an example as to how that can work in practice, consider a generic `selectionSort` like

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void selectionSort(T[] arr) {
    int index = 0, i = 0, length = (arr != null) ? arr.length : 0, j;
    for (; i < length - 1; index = ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < length; ++j) {
            if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[index]) < 0) {
                index = j; // <-- here we update the index when we find a smaller value
            }
        }
        if (i != index) { // <-- if i == index then it is in the correct position
            swap(arr, i, index);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** that we could also do it with a `Comparator`;

```
static <T> void selectionSort(T[] arr, Comparator<T> comp) {
    int index = 0, i = 0, length = (arr != null) ? arr.length : 0, j;
    for (; i < length - 1; index = ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < length; ++j) {
            if (comp.compare(arr[j], arr[index]) < 0) {
                index = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != index) {
            swap(arr, i, index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is completely lost to me I'm afarid, I just started java about a week ago. Thanks for your help though.